# Where am I going wrong setting up bxSlider slideshow?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a slideshow for my rails site. for this i am following the instructions on the bxSlider website [bxslider website link](http://bxslider.com/)

Here are the steps i followed as indicated on the site.

How to install

Step 1: Link required files

First and most important, the jQuery library needs to be included (no need to download - link directly from Google). Next, download the package from this site and link the bxSlider CSS file (for the theme) and the bxSlider Javascript file.

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">               </script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Step 2: Create HTML markup

Create a `<ul class="bxslider">` element, with a `<li>` for each slide. Slides can contain images, video, or any other HTML content!

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Step 3: Call the bxSlider

Call `.bxslider()` on `<ul class="bxslider">`. Note that the call must be made inside of a `$(document).ready()` call, or the plugin will not work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

and here is where i added these files. since it doesnt say where to add them i copied some youtube videos but they all seem to not exactly follow these 3 steps and each does it slightly differently.

below is the application.html.erb file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects Daughter">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great Vibes">


    <title>Acupuntura Simon Verde</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="/images/bamboo.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/bamboo2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/treatment1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/treatment2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
    </script>
    <!-- <div id="container">
            <div id="mainpic">
                <h1><span class="off2">Acupuntura Cosmetica</span></h1>
                <h2>Simon Verde</h2>
            </div> -->

<div id="menu">
<ul>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Inicio</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">La Acupuntura</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Sobre Nosotros</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tratamientos</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Precios</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Testimonials</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="menuitem">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Contacto</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="new">Formulario de contacato</a>
        <!-- <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a> -->
      </div>
  </div>
</li>


<!-- <li class="menuitem"><a href="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
<li class="menuitem"><a href="sobre">La Acupuntura</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>Para quien es</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Como funciona</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>something else</a></li>
  </ul>
</li> -->


      <!-- <li class="menuitem"><a href="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="sobre">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="acupuntura">La Acupuntura</a></li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="tratamientos">Tratamientos</a></li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="prensa">Prensa</a></li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="new">Contacto</a></li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content">

                <p>jjj</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>

                <%= yield %>

                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                <div id="footer"><h3><a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">Acupuntura Simon Verde</a></div>
          </div>
       </div>






  </body>
</html>
```

am I putting something in the worng place or missing something? thanks

EDIT: adding css errors.

```
Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.self-e8159e2f25b88e4811b048150ba7ed4782f9097a2c773a91921af1976ef07077.css:10:2

Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  

Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.self-e8159e2f25b88e4811b048150ba7ed4782f9097a2c773a91921af1976ef07077.css:32:17

Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.self-e8159e2f25b88e4811b048150ba7ed4782f9097a2c773a91921af1976ef07077.css:72:20

Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.self-e8159e2f25b88e4811b048150ba7ed4782f9097a2c773a91921af1976ef07077.css:85:2

Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.self-e8159e2f25b88e4811b048150ba7ed4782f9097a2c773a91921af1976ef07077.css:86:2

Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.min.self-20800de2808abed56c80e727b78530acbb6a5813a63c095606d36c08b557fcc1.css:1:116

Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.min.self-20800de2808abed56c80e727b78530acbb6a5813a63c095606d36c08b557fcc1.css:1:911

Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped.  style.self-49aba9bf3c33acfe5778acd4415ffe78d6e2f9c3473fb11430b014a18ad22038.css:87:9

Expected colour but found '#black'.  Error in parsing value for 'color'.  Declaration dropped.  style.self-
49aba9bf3c33acfe5778acd4415ffe78d6e2f9c3473fb11430b014a18ad22038.css:123:9

Error in parsing value for 'margin-bottom'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.css:7:17

Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.css:9:2

Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.css:31:17

Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.  jquery.bxslider.css:71:20

Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.css:84:2

Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.  jquery.bxslider.css:85:2

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  jquery.min.js:2:40278

GET 
http://localhost:3000/assets/style.self-49aba9bf3c33acfe5778acd4415ffe78d6e2f9c3473fb11430b014a18ad22038.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

GET 
http://localhost:3000/assets/style.self-49aba9bf3c33acfe5778acd4415ffe78d6e2f9c3473fb11430b014a18ad22038.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Check both on server and client (i.e. javascript).

Comment: Also, check that you have the downloaded files in the public directory (or asset pipeline).

Comment: @Gerry. There is no error just that nothing shows related to the slider. The rest of the page loads correctly. i believe the files are all in the asset pipeline, if by this you mean in the app/assets folder.

Comment: Can you confirm (using dev tools in your navigator) that the related assets (`/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js` and `/lib/jquery.bxslider.css`) are loading correctly?

Comment: @Gerry. you mean the "inspect element" function?  how will i know if they are loading correctly

Comment: Yes, open your browser, right click on "inspect" and that will open dev tools. If there are javascript errors, you will see them there, and you can also view the assets that the page is actually loading.

Comment: @Gerry. under the "console" tab i see the error `TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function[Learn More]`

Comment: The function `.bxSlider` is not available, most likely your assets are not loading properly. How are you loading `jquery.bxslider.min.js`?

Comment: @Gerry. i just put the line inside <script> tags in the application.html.erb  like the instructions said. the instructions dont specify where to put the code inside the app which is what i find confusing. they are very vague and all the tutorials i saw didnt exactly follow them and did extra bits with no explanation

Comment: So yes, you need to load the assets, check my answer for detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the required assets are not present, so you need to download the `.js` and `.css` files from [bxslider.com](http://www.bxslider.com) and add them to your project.

Download the .zip file, and add the required files into the public folder:

- `css/jquery.bxslider.css`
- `js/jquery.bxslider.min.js`

`css` and `js` are folders that you must create and put your files inside them.

Then, in `application.html.erb` update the lines where you call those assets:

```
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Finally, add the images that come in the same .zip you downloaded also in your public folder inside a "images" folder.

**UPDATE**

To use the asset pipeline, you should change the way your are loading your assets (that is, images, javascripts and styelsheets) in `application.html.erb`; instead of referencing for them from `/lib/`, `js`, `images`, you should reference them from `assets`, like this:

**application.html.erb** (just showing the relevant code):

```
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/assets/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

...

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/assets/bamboo.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/bamboo2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/treatment1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/treatment2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/assets/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

Next you must update also the `jquery.bxslider.css` file to also reference all images from `/assets/` instead of `images/`, so change:

- `url('images/bx_loader.gif')` to `url('/assets/bx_loader.gif')` and
- `url('images/controls.png')` to `url('/assets/controls.png')` (4 occurrences)

Now you can add your `.js` to `app/assets/javascripts`, `.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets` and images to `app/assets/images`.

For more information about the asset pipeline take a look at the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: i already added all css and js files, there are no more to add. but if i create a public/css file then what is the code inside that file?

Comment: Where did you add the `js` and `css` files? You don't need to create any file, you just need to make the files available for your view (the ones downloaded from bxslider.com). In `public/js` put the `jquery.bxslider.min.js` file, and in `public/css` put the `jquery.bxslider.css` file.

Comment: i added all the js files in the app/assets/javascript folder and all the css files in the app/assets/stylesheets folder.  should the app not detect them if they are in here. what is the difference between putting them here and putting them in the public folder?

Comment: should i only put this js file or all 4 js files that came in the download? same with 2 css files.

Comment: UPDATE: i have added all files into folders js, css and images in the public folder.  now what shows is the small circles that indicate what photo in the slideshow you are in but still not photos showing.

Comment: Yes, it should pick up all assets within `app/assets` directory, but your app was not doing it, so we first are serving them directly from the `public` directory. Since your images are not loading at all, maybe they are not being picked up either, so try adding them to `public/images` folder as well. Again, you can use your browser dev tools to see if there is any javascript error.

Comment: there seems to be some functionality now. photos appear but i also have the following error. `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead` . what does this error mean?

Comment: and another error "Stylesheet coudl not be loaded. http://localhost:3000/assets/acupuntura.self e3b0 (lots of random letters and numbers here) .css?body=1"

Comment: The first error may be coming from another script, do you have additional `.js` files? Does the slider works ok now? The second error refers to another `.css` (or `.scss`) file that you are trying to load somewhere in your code but now is not available. My guess is that you moved the `acupuntura.scss` file to `public/css` as well, i meant to move only the relevant bxslider files to public (sorry if i wasn't clear for that). But check my updated answer, i added the details you need to use the asset pipeline (that is, `app/assets` directory) correctly.

Comment: I also suggest using Chrome's incognito window or Firefox's private window so you don't need to erase cookies/cache every time you update your assets.

Comment: slider works in a manual way. i am having some trouble configuring it. i.e. changing to automatic and there is a white space underneath. it seems as if most of the styling is not working now. when i play with the settings nothing happens. it seems not to detect another stylesheet i had in there before style.css.scss. i havent moved the acupuntura.scss into the public folder yet but i did copy the style.css.scss in there, but it had no effect. what could be a reason that the style.css.scss file isnt being detected? it stopped working after the slide show began working. thanks for all the advice

Comment: Can you check if `style.css.scss` is loaded? Use dev tools, there tou can see all assets that were loaded.

Comment: style.css.scss seems to work now. however i am getting a bunch of css errors.  this would make sence as i am having great trouble configuring the slider. i.e. resizing pcitures to be the same size and also the position of the slider on the page. i am changing options but nothing changes on screen. i will add the css errors in the main question.

Comment: im sorry but i dont know where to look to find out what assets are loaded.

Comment: It seems that you may altered the `.js` file while configuring it. Can you double check that the syntax is correct? You could replace the file with a new one (save your current changes in other file) just to be sure.